# @angular point to the correct node_module

Tags: angular

I am looking through a variety of angular 5 files trying to figure out how "@angular" points to the correct node_modules folder and then subsequently the correct sub-modules within that folder (i.e. router) if imported.  There doesn't appear to be a file which explicitly defines the configuration path for the @angular "app" name, if you will.

I was looking for something like this: "@angugular": "./nodes_module/@angular" but have not discovered it.

I am using Angular 5 on Mac OS if that means anything.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to know it?

Comment: I have an app that I would like to import by name rather than its node module path name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something specific to Angular. It's a Typescript configuration.

If you look in your `tsconfig.json` (`tsconfig.app.json` if you're using the CLI), you should see a `moduleResolution` property:

```
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

The 'node' mode means the Typescript compiler will attempt to resolve modules just like Node.JS would, which means `node_modules` will always be a root for module resolution. Anything in `node_modules` is importable via an absolute path this way -- assuming the packages' Typescript definition file is in its root path, this means it is importable just by referencing the folder name. There's some good documentation on that [here.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)

@angular generates its Typescript definition files in a modular fashion in subfolders, so you need to reference the folder path to that file (e.g. `@angular/core`).

Another [tsconfig.json](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) property that the Typescript compiler uses to find modules or exports is the `baseUrl` property. Setting something here will allow the compiler to treat that path as an absolute path (example: setting `baseUrl` to `"src"` in an Angular app will allow you to import things absolutely from that, so `import { Thing } from ../../../services/thing` can become `import { Thing } from app/services/thing`.)

You can also pass the compiler a `paths` object that will add additional path mapping to modules, relative to the `baseUrl`.